# preg_match_all returning undesired html text with desired text

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am currently struggling with preg_match_all

I am trying to write a program that fetches powerball numbers and inserts them into a mysql database for further manipulation. although i would like for them to be inserted as date, white numbers, powerball in one row, i will concentrate on that after i fix the tag issue. I am using a bit of source code from the actual powerball website as the $url variable.

here is my code:

```
$url='localhost/lotto/test.html';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resultDate = curl_exec($ch);
$resultNum = curl_exec($ch);
$resultPb = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
$link1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lotto");
    if($link1 === false){
        die("ERROR: could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else {
        echo "Connection Established </br>";
    }
        preg_match_all("/<b>(.+?)<\/font>/", $resultDate, $dates);
            for ($d=0; $d<count($resultDate); $d++) {
                preg_match_all("/white_40.gif\" class=\"cssNumber-24\">(.+?)<\/td>/", $resultNum, $numbers);
            for($n=0; $n<count($resultNum); $n++) {
                preg_match_all("/red_40\.gif\" class=\"cssNumber-24\">(.+?)<\/td>/", $resultPb, $pb);
            for($p=0; $p<count($resultPb); $p++) {      
                foreach(array($dates[$d]) as $date) {
                    for ($q=0;$q<count($date);$q++){
                        foreach(array($numbers[$n]) as $number) {
                            for ($i=0; $i<count($number); $i++) {
                                foreach (array($pb[$p]) as $power) {
                                    for ($w=0;$w<count($power);$w++){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO Winners (dates,white,power) VALUES ('$date[$q]','$number[$i]','$power[$w]')";
        if(mysqli_query($link1, $sql)){
            echo "Data added successfully. </br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link1);
        }
                    }
                }
                    }
                }
                    }
                }
mysqli_close($link1);
}
    }
        }   






curl_close($ch);
```

desired result: 
`11/12/2013` inserted into mysql

undesired results:
`<b>11/12/2013</font>` inserted into mysql instead

Note: there are thousands of dates.
also note: I am very new to php so go easy on the criticisms lol.

Comment: well regular expressions are for regular languages, unlike HTML.

Comment: Running your `preg_match_all` through regex101.com it returns the correct result. What is wrong? what is your source data block?

Comment: well i am using curl to fetch a url, locate the data i am looking for the insert that data into a mysql database. I can echo the results and it shows desired results, but inserting it into mysql it shows up in the database with the `<b>` and `</font>. is there something i am missing?

Comment: @ovranon This question seems to have stalled / been abandoned.  Do you still seek resolution for this question?  I am willing to help you, if you can provide a very small yet relevant sample of what `$resultDate` might hold.  I am confident that I can refine your process as well.  Now it is up to you to either delete this old question or provide some additional information.  Let's resolve this page one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Your preg_match_all regex is currently:

> `preg_match_all("/\<b\>(.*?)\<\/font\>/",$resultDate, $dates);`

which has excess escape characters which are just not needed. Reduce this down to:

```
preg_match_all("/<b>(.*?)<\\/font>/",$resultDate, $dates);
```

and this -- ie your current regex -- appears to work as you want, check it out on https://regex101.com/r/sP6lH7/1

Comment: all of the excess escapes were because i could not locate the error and got frustrated lol. thank you for your quick response though

Comment: @ovranon did it solve you issue? Your regex looked and acted correctly so I would need more information to diagnose why you are getting inaccurate results

Comment: I have edited the code in the original post. but even after working on this for days, I still can't figure out why it shows up in mysql with the tags.